# Android application giving a weird error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i put this question in this forum because i am not sure whether this is an eclipse error or an Android error.
yesterday i created an Android application using Google Maps and GPS on Eclipse and it build and ran successfully however today i wanted to do some modification to the code so i started eclipse but it gave me an error.

```
SDK parse failed
```

if i try to run it. it says the apk cannot find. how can that be happened? the same application ran successfully on the same environment yesterday. i am using Ubuntu 10.04

Thanks !!

[image]

Comment: what happens when u build it......

Comment: nothing happens. build successfully without any errors or warnings.

Comment: if it's building then it should run, does it gives error after building, also try what "Juhani " said  ...

Comment: i think there is a problem with android.jar file. i will attach a screenshot

Comment: Try right clicking on the project `> Android Tools > Fix Project Properties`, then a clean project.

Comment: Try refreshing the project? (Select the project and click F5)

Comment: If nothing else works, make sure you have the latest update of the android sdk manager installed along with anything that might be an issue within eclipse and restart eclipse. If you still think everything is set up correctly then delete the error and attempt to run the app from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your project, as evidenced by the red x icon on your project title bar shown in the image above. Right-click your project, choose Properties and go through all your properties to make sure they are all still valid. It might be a reference to one of the jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem all the time, hopefully my solution works for you.

To work around, goto your libraries inside the properties page.
Add any library and then rebuild your project.

Go back and remove the library later for clean up.
The project should still build.